# PHP fputcsv() in not working properly

Tags: php, csv, xls, forms, http-post

I want to put the out -put of HTML form in a csv file having header names: "NAME", "EMAIL", "WEB".  But the following PHP code is not working. Could any body help in this?

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("my_file.xls", "a");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$web   = $_POST['web'];

if (!$fp) {
    print("Could not open to file");
    exit;
}

fput($fp, "NAME", "EMAIL",'WEB");
fputcsv($fp, $name, $email, $web);

print("Thanks you ");

fclose($fp);
?>
```

I have tried by replacing `my_file.xls` with `my-file.csv`. After submission of HTML form, the output is blank CSV file.

Expected : Comma separated values from the `form` with Headers.

Please help me locate the issue.

Comment: "PHP code is not working" -> what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$fp = fopen("my_file.xls", "a");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$web   = $_POST['web'];

if (!$fp) {
    print("Could not open to file");
    exit;
}
fputs($fp, "NAME,EMAIL,WEB");        
fputcsv($fp,array($name, $email, $web));

print("Thanks you ");

fclose($fp);
```

[`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) expects an array of values as a second parameter and `fput` should be [`fputs`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputs.php) and expects a string as a second parameter

Comment: I hope you get a green tick for all the effort.

Comment: @Pete not the end of the world if I dont ... Im used to being lazy and using frameworks rather than raw PHP - im learning here too ...

Comment: @web Nope - what is generated is a CSV file .. because you are using `fputcsv` .. if you want a XLS file thats a whole different task ... have a look at [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) for that

Comment: If the file name is changed to "my_file.csv" still the code is not working. on submitting of HTML form, simple CSV file is generated with any data.

Comment: @web *code is not working* ... why not ?... what happens ? what errors do you get ? please dont just copy/paste and answer and run it and expect it to do exactly as you think it will - take some time to understand the answer ....